# GTK# button drawn incorrectly?

Tags: button, gtk, gtk#

My GTK# (v2.12.44) app has a single Window with a single button on it.  The button appears to be centered on the Window, because that's where the text appears, but the border/background for the button is shifted up and to the left for no reason I can see.  Has anyone seen this before?  I saw similar behavior from an Image widget.  Note this only happens in Windows, not on (for example) Raspberry Pi/Jesse.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
Application.Init();
var window = new Window("test") {new Button("testing 1, 2, 3")};
window.Maximize();
window.ShowAll();
Application.Run();
```

Comment: What version of GTK+?

Comment: I'm using version 2.12.44.

Comment: That sounds particularly ancient. Try updating to a newer version (the latest GTK+ 2 is 2.24; the latest GTK+ 3 is 3.22).

Comment: That's the version of GTK#...it uses GTK 2.24;

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well. Try to add a container before adding a button and set some parametrs you want to. Fill and Expand when adding Button.